# How to encode/compress gltf to draco

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I want to compress/encode gltf file using draco programatically in threejs with reactjs. I dont want to use any commandline tool, I want it to be done programatically. Please suggest me a solution.

I tried using gltf-pipeline but its not working in client side. Cesium library was showing error when I used it in reactjs.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a client-only JavaScript implementation of the Draco encoder, only the decoder.

Comment: can we use gltf-pipeline for draco compression in client side(Reactjs) ??

Comment: Oh sorry, I was wrong.  I guess they did get both encoding and decoding hooked up, at least in NodeJS code in gltf-pipeline.  I've never tried running that client-side in a browser though, not sure how to make that work.

Comment: thanks for the reply much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is can be implemented with [glTF-Transform](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/). There's also an [open feature request on three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/21492), not yet implemented.

First you'll need to [download the Draco encoder/decoder libraries](https://github.com/google/draco/tree/master/javascript) (the versions currently published to NPM do not work client side), host them in a folder, and then load them as global script tags. There should be six files, and two script tags (which will load the remaining files).

Files:

- draco_decoder.js
- draco_decoder.wasm
- draco_wasm_wrapper.js
- draco_encoder.js
- draco_encoder.wasm
- draco_encoder_wrapper.js

```html
<script src="assets/draco_encoder.js"></script>
<script src="assets/draco_decoder.js"></script>
```

Then you'll need to write code to load a GLB file, apply compression, and do something with the compressed result. This will require first installing the two packages shown below, and then bundling the web application with your tool of choice (I used https://www.snowpack.dev/ here).

```js
import { WebIO } from '@gltf-transform/core';
import { DracoMeshCompression } from '@gltf-transform/extensions';

const io = new WebIO()
    .registerExtensions([DracoMeshCompression])
    .registerDependencies({
        'draco3d.encoder': await new DracoEncoderModule(),
        'draco3d.decoder': await new DracoDecoderModule(),
    });

// Load an uncompressed GLB file.
const document = await io.read('./assets/Duck.glb');

// Configure compression settings.
document.createExtension(DracoMeshCompression)
    .setRequired(true)
    .setEncoderOptions({
        method: DracoMeshCompression.EncoderMethod.EDGEBREAKER,
        encodeSpeed: 5,
        decodeSpeed: 5,
    });

// Create compressed GLB, in an ArrayBuffer.
const arrayBuffer = await io.writeBinary(document); // Promise<ArrayBuffer>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I want to compress a scene. I think with ```WebIO``` I can only give file uri. Is it possible to directly give file or blob instead of uri?

Comment: @VikramHegde might be best to start a new question or discussion thread on GitHub, but a File can be decoded to JSON or Uint8Array and WebIO can parse that. Or you can use URL.createObjectURL to turn a Blob into a URI.

Comment: Related discussion on Draco packaging: https://github.com/google/draco/issues/977

Answer (score -1):

In the latest version of 1.5.0, what are these two files?  draco_decoder_gltf.js and draco_encoder_gltf.js.  Does this means we no longer need the draco_encoder and draco_decoder files?  and how do we invoke the transcoder interface without using MeshBuilder.  A simpler API would be musth better.

Comment: Don't ask counter questions while writing an answer. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30609543)