# Convert glb to draco glb front end

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl, gltf

Is there any way to encode and convert glb files to draco glb in frontend only (client side)?

Comment: Possible duplicate in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054435/how-to-encode-compress-gltf-to-draco. I haven't copied my answer there, to avoid having a duplicate answer flagged.

Comment: Since this question has been closed, I've moved my answer to the version of the question that remains open, linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is can be implemented with [glTF-Transform](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/). There's also an [open feature request on three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/21492), not yet implemented.

First you'll need to [download the Draco encoder/decoder libraries](https://github.com/google/draco/tree/master/javascript) (the versions currently published to NPM do not work client side), host them in a folder, and then load them as global script tags. There should be six files, and two script tags (which will load the remaining files).

Files:

- draco_decoder.js
- draco_decoder.wasm
- draco_wasm_wrapper.js
- draco_encoder.js
- draco_encoder.wasm
- draco_encoder_wrapper.js

```html
<script src="assets/draco_encoder.js"></script>
<script src="assets/draco_decoder.js"></script>
```

Then you'll need to write code to load a GLB file, apply compression, and do something with the compressed result. This will require first installing the two packages shown below, and then bundling the web application with your tool of choice (I used https://www.snowpack.dev/ here).

```js
import { WebIO } from '@gltf-transform/core';
import { DracoMeshCompression } from '@gltf-transform/extensions';

const io = new WebIO()
    .registerExtensions([DracoMeshCompression])
    .registerDependencies({
        'draco3d.encoder': await new DracoEncoderModule(),
        'draco3d.decoder': await new DracoDecoderModule(),
    });

// Load an uncompressed GLB file.
const document = await io.read('./assets/Duck.glb');

// Configure compression settings.
document.createExtension(DracoMeshCompression)
    .setRequired(true)
    .setEncoderOptions({
        method: DracoMeshCompression.EncoderMethod.EDGEBREAKER,
        encodeSpeed: 5,
        decodeSpeed: 5,
    });

// Create compressed GLB, in an ArrayBuffer.
const arrayBuffer = io.writeBinary(document); // ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution it's working very well
as i am working/implemented this project https://threejs.org/editor/
i see that only direct light is being compressed with DracoEncoder 
but not AmbientLight by example and parameter shadow cast/received is not being compressed also
do you have a solution for that?
Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: Not all three.js features are representable in the glTF format — THREE.AmbientLight and shadow-casting properties cannot be exported for example. The three.js forums would be a good source for questions about these features: https://discourse.threejs.org/