# The latest Draco 1.5.0 and GLTF on the client side

Tags: javascript, client, gltf

In the latest version of Draco 1.5.0, what are these two files? draco_decoder_gltf.js and draco_encoder_gltf.js. Does this means we no longer need the draco_encoder and draco_decoder files? and how do we invoke the transcoder interface without needing MeshBuilder. A simpler API would be musth easier.  such as:

```
var encodedGlb = Transcode( glb );
var glb = Transcode( encodedGlb );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Draco library does not directly read or write glTF files, so using it requires the low-level mesh interface.  The `_gltf.js` files are *smaller* versions of the full Draco library, containing only features needed for the glTF format, but they still don't read/write glTF files. You could use a higher-level library like glTF-Transform for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978236/1314762  - I haven't updated this for Draco 1.5.0 yet, though.